# flask celery redis not returning value

Tags: python, redis, celery

Trying to learn how to implement celery.  I have a working example and i do a redis-cli monitor and i see it gets the value and returns it to the browser,  but when I change the example to my own thing,  I see it gives me a key, but when I try to view the result of the key, expecing it to print 'testing123', it hangs and redis-cli monitor shows endless 'get's for the celery task.

WORKING...

```
celery = make_celery(app)

@celery.task(name="tasks.add")
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@app.route("/test")
def hello_world(x=16, y=16):
    x = int(request.args.get("x", x))
    y = int(request.args.get("y", y))
    res = add.apply_async((x, y))
    context = {"id": res.task_id, "x": x, "y": y}
    result = "add((x){}, (y){})".format(context['x'], context['y'])
    goto = "{}".format(context['id'])
    return jsonify(result=result, goto=goto)

@app.route("/test/result/<task_id>")
def show_result(task_id):
    retval = add.AsyncResult(task_id).get(timeout=1.0)
    return repr(retval)
```

NOT WORKING...

```
@celery.task(name="tasks.yieldsomething")
def yieldsomething():
    a = 'test123'
    return a


@app.route("/yield")
def helloworld2():
    res = yieldsomething.apply_async()
    return res.task_id


@app.route("/yield/result/<task_id2>")
def show_result2(task_id2):
    aretval = yieldsomething.AsyncResult(task_id2).get()
    return repr(aretval)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my problem, celery was not running in the background anymore.  after restarting it, it worked correctly.